# jQuery $.post PHP whats the best way to handle a multidimensional object or array

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json, multidimensional-array

Ok, I usually do this in reverse, post a specific data set, then expect an JSON object back, however. In today's case I kinda need to the opposite. Except my confusion is brought on by there is no static elements to work with. My data won't be coming from a customary form, so serialization is not an option I don't think. So before I go more into it a little info on the spec

I have a Unordered list that can have anywhere from 1 List Element to dozens, each one contains 3 pieces if info I need to pass in a POST to my PHP as I would a form. But Im not sure whats the best way to handle it.

Can I pass it as an array through the post where the array is what it is? Or do I have to transform the output to resemble a JSON object and post that, treating it as a JSON object with the PHP and running it through json_decode? Not sure what to do here, so any advice is greatly appreciated.

*edit* worth mentioning is I can get the data I need from the list elements, its just what should I do with it to pass it in a post, so that it posts in sense like its a multidimensional object or array

Comment: Why cannot you just pass array as array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You **can** pass the array from js using ajax as array. And it will come to `$_POST` as array without any additional steps

Comment: +1, excellent. Not sure why I thought it couldn't be done, but this is much simpler.

Comment: Thats what I was thinking, but needed some validation on it. Also come to find out the way I was posting it while trying to play was a bit off so that didn't help me much, but finding my error, and being told here its plausible is a +1 for me, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to transform it into a JSON string and then json_decode it on the other side. This is where node.js can be superior as a backend because you can pass the array directly to Node without going into and out of JSON.

Comment: Oh please don't argue for nodejs only by its automatic JSON transformation (especially in cases when json is not necessary at all)